# HDMI not showing up as sound device

Tags: audio, hdmi, nvidia-settings

I am using nvidia. My PC connects to a TV that have sound. However, HDMI not showing up.

This is the screenshot

I have updated the driver
[image]

As you see in the screenshot in nvidia settings, if I go to set up digital audio I see that the nvidia software can detect my TV as sound device, which is LG M2341A.

However, HDMI doesn't show up.

The problem is it has shown up before.

No HDMI shows up in devices manager either

[image]

Notice it USED to work. One day my computer didn't work. Someone repair the power supply and it no longer works.

HDMI doesn't show up under in device manager under sound, video and game controller

I think that's the root of the problem. Perhaps someone delete it. How to turn it back on?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not all Nvidia graphics cards are capable of passing audio via HDMI, and if you are using an adapter from DVI to HDMI that may also remove audio options.  If you know that yours is capable but you still have this problem, what is the model of video card you are using?  What version of the Nvidia driver do you have installed?  If you answer the above questions, I can help you.

Some models of the 9400 GT were able to connect via an internal SPDIF header to supply audio.  Internal audio decoding was not a native feature of video cards of that age.

Comment: it used to work.

Comment: What is the change that you have made from the time it used to work until now?  Is all of the hardware the same?  Is the operating system the same?

Comment: everything is the same. Perhaps some driver update

Answer (score 0):

This is a 10% tentative answer.

Basically I am supposed to plug in s/pdif cable to my GT 9400

http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=60454

> AFAIK, you can't get audio into the HDMI signal through the PCI-E
>   connector (at least, not with the 9400GT).
>
> Your card should have an SPDIF header, and probably came with a cable
>   to connect to a motherboard SPDIF header. However, since you said your
>   motherboard doesn't have SPDIF, you're going to need a sound card that
>   has an SPDIF header, I suppose.

Make sure and check that you have the headers connected properly; those cables aren't universal.

There are several sites that say this.

The thing is I have no idea where that s/pdif cable is. I guess I'll just bring this to mechanic.

I finally got my problem solved.

Basically I go all the way to a store and change my video card into a realtek one.

While that works perfectly, mistery remains. Nvidia is a very popular card and all computer engineers in Jakarta would say that they never insert spdif cable. Nvidia should have worked too. Internet says it doesn't but there are tons of nvidia video card using users that would testify differently. This problem should not have existed in the first place even with nvidia card.